# Как в Qt из QLineEdit вытащить значение конкретной позиции

Tags: qt5

Есть проблема. В QLineEdit вручную вводится время. Как получить доступ к вводимым знакам, чтобы сравнить их с каким-нибудь эталоном. Например введено 05:12:00. Как в переменную вывести значение первого символа. Или любого другого.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте метод `QLineEdit::text()`, который вернёт объект класса строки `QString`. А из него доступ к любому из символов можно получить посредством метода `QString::at()` или оператора `QString::operator[]`.

Пример:

```
QLineEdit *ledit = new QLineEdit(this);

// ... ввод данных пользователем ...

// Получение содержимого поля ввода.
QString txt = ledit->text();

// Посимвольный вывод строки.
for(int i = 0; i < txt.size(); ++i)
    qDebug() << txt[i];
```

Если предполагается, что в поле ввода будут заноситься дата и/или время, то можно использовать соответствующие виджеты, как то `QDateTimeEdit` и `QDateEdit`. В них уже реализован весь необходимый функционал по парсингу и проверке вводимых пользователем данных.